# APT-GET behind a proxy with Digest Authentication

Tags: squid, apt, curl, wget, proxy-authentication

I'd like to use apt-get (and other ubuntu tools) to download software and keep it updated.

Unfortunately, my company has set a squid proxy to accept digest authentication only. I've seen somewhere (can't find the link again) that APT-GET uses WGET, which doesn't support digest authentication, to download the packages.

**Is it possible to configure APT-GET to use CURL instead of WGET to download the packages?**

Comment: As a way around you can use redsocks (http://www.darkk.net.ru/redsocks/)
look here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1035050/828826

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apt uses its own fetcher (`/usr/lib/apt/methods/http`), not wget, so your literal question is unanswerable.  Going a little broader, according to a `strings` over that file, `Proxy-Authentication: Basic` is supported, but there's no mention of `Digest`, so I'm going to guess that you're out of luck.